# Is it possible to delete the browser cache data?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps, browser-cache

I have an Angular PWA which I configured using a service worker. The service worker was caching large PDF files, however this resulted in massive cache stores for some of our users.
More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76471449/handle-angular-pwa-excessive-cache-size).

I'm considering adding the function below to be called whenever a new version of my app is loaded, however while testing this on an environment, while it does delete the cache entries - none of the data is removed from the browser cache store.

```
async removeAllCaches(cacheName: string){
    const allCaches = await caches.keys();
    const applicableCaches = allCaches.filter(c => c.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(cacheName.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1);

    for(var key of applicableCaches){
      await caches.delete(key);
    }
  }
```

Before and after cache storage size remains the same:

[image]

Is it possible to delete the browser cache data programmatically?
I also know there's an [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24008) about handling this, but I'm specific about deleting the *data* of the cache.

Comment: I hope not. I don't think I want a website clearing data from my computer, whether it put it there or not.

Comment: @evolutionxbox You can only clear your 'own' cache

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler good good. That's encouraging to know

Comment: From my understanding, I can clear the cache entries with the code I've posted above, but this doesn't clear the data associated with those cache entries

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - see my comment above :) Forgot to tag you.

Comment: If the PDFs have a URL or you trigger a download via JS, you can probably add a [HTTP cache control header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) or equivalent. The browser will still run the garbage collection whenever it wants, supposedly when the storage quota is reached. You can give the cache-control headers a value from yesterday to prevent caching IIRC.

Comment: @PeterKrebs - Is it correct that I cache these PDFs in the first place? We had a couple users that had cache sizes exceeding 20Gb - as they navigate through MANY of these documents in a day, with the service worker allowing the documents to be stored in the cache storage so the reload times of documents they revisit are shorter.

Comment: The browser should get rid of its cache at some point, 20GB seems very large. Caching the PDFs for a while is certainly not a bad move, but caching them forever seems impractical. Is the progressive web-app so large that it contains gigabytes of PDFs? Or are those downloads you could influence with HTTP cache-control headers? What if a PDF is updated? The browser would use the cached version if the URL stays the same.

Comment: @PeterKrebs  - using my screenshot above as an example, Chromium browsers tend to use 50% of the available hard drive space as the cache storage limit, so 20Gb would be well within my 600Gb threshold. The issue is that my users don't all have the latest and greatest SSDs on their devices, so read times degrade affecting their experience. The PDFs are read from an Azure Storage account, and not part of the PWA itself. The URLs remain the same, and PDFs aren't modify-able :)